# Negative records of first column of SQL Server query are not exported in CSV/Text

Tags: sql-server, csv, export, sqlcmd

I have the below code in a batch file.
Here MYDB is the database, `Activity_Inc.sql` is the script file and `ST_Activity-` is the csv file generated with the data. `|` is used as the delimiter. Now, the problem is with few records of the first column of the table. The first column of the SQL query output is having negative values in it. But when the data is exported in csv or txt, these negative records of the first column are not exported.

Data in DB is like below. **The first 14 records are not getting exported.
 Please suggest a way to manage this.**


[image]

```
sqlcmd -S . -d MYDB -E -s"|" -W -i D:\Activity_Inc.sql | findstr /V /C:"-" /B > D:\ST_Activity-%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.csv
```

Comment: You have a complex command. I suspect the problem is not the exporting but the additional processing you apply. In addition, no one but you can evaluate what your script file contains. Break your problem into pieces to find the problem.

Comment: Do you think `findstr /V /C:"-" /B` could have something to do with it? Have you checked the [findstr documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) to see what it does?